# Cannot create pyspark dataframe on pandas pipelinedRDD

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

```
list_of_df = process_pitd_objects(objects) # returns a list of dataframes
list_rdd = sc.parallelize(list_of_df)
spark_df_list = list_rdd.map(lambda x: spark.createDataFrame(x)).collect()
```

So I have a list of dataframes in python and I want to convert each dataframe to pyspark. I want to do it on the worker node so I am parallelising using sc.parallelise. when I call the spark.createDataFrame on list_rdd.map, I get the following error: **"PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063"**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide full code or a simple version to reproduce the problem? I need a sample of your "list of dataframes". I think the problem is you're using "spark.createDataFrame(x)" inside a map function. First, try to use "sc" instead of "spark" to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Just simple pandas dataframes. Also, it does not work with sc